# Get MySQL table.column named records with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

I have the normal column name:

> SELECT **column** FROM....

The way i retrieve it in PHP:

```
$var = $row["column"];
```

What i want to know is how to retrieve column records which are named with column and table:

> SELECT **table.column** FROM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the exact same way, it's not going to be prefixed with a table.

so if you do a `SELECT table.* FROM` ..., and one of the column names is tacos. you can still do `$row['tacos']`.

Now, if you're doing multiple tables (joins) it can get ambiguous if they have the same names, such as "id".  So you can alias them... `SELECT table.column as new_name FROM` ...

Answer (score 1):

You won't get them returned with *table.column*.  Perhaps use an alias?  Could use a delimiter between table / field name part.

```
SELECT column AS tableName_ColumnName FROM....
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're trying to select from multiple tables which can be done by using joins:

Lets say you have 3 tables that you need to obtain information from all by a unique ID.  You can accomplish this by using a left join:

```
SELECT a.uniqid, a.testingDate, a.testscore, a.testresults,b.email_addy, b.phone1, c.testlevel as tlevel 
FROM Tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 b
ON a.Tbl1 = b.Tbl2 
LEFT JOIN Tbl3 c
on a.Tbl1 = c.Tbl3
```

you can then pull the information just as you always do: $var = $row['testingdate']